# Ubuntu 16.04 on Macbook 8,1 CPU and integrated GPU overheating issues

Tags: macbook, overheating

Just did a fresh wipe/install on a Macbook 8,1 that was given to me from UEFI USB. I have a personal hatred for OSX. It has decent machine specs, and I am getting into Linux because I work in IT. I'm a Jr. Sys Admin, but I mainly work with Windows, so I'm no noob to computers, just have a bit of a green thumb with Linux, I do know my basics though.

I've searched and searched with my Google-Fu skills, and am coming up short. I'm thinking I might need to go back to an earlier release of Ubuntu (14.04 I believe?), but I wanted to check here first.

I installed psensor and am seeing it's running between 60-70C which is a little hot for my tastes when I'm currently just browsing the web.

I've tried:

mbpfan to hardset the fan. it's sticking to around 2000RPM and won't go up to 6000RPM

2 different Intel Drivers, the one that's stock, and the one from "Additional Drivers"

Everything else I'm reading pops up with Nvidia drivers, but from my understanding this model does not have a dedicated GPU, when I run lshw I do not see an additional card.

It sucks because everything else is working splendid (Touchpad (including 2 finger scroll OOB), key brightness, screen brightness, sound, plays videos via Kodi/youtube/netflix, usb, charging indication, etc).

If anyone could help me point me in the right direction of alternative drivers, or at least point me in the right direction of and older release that might work better I'd appreciate it.

If I didn't provide enough information please let me know, I know many basic commands.

Comment: what card does it have, you didn't mention

Comment: That might be helpful huh lol. CPU i7 2640M Integrated Graphics Card Intel HD Graphics 3000

Comment: Have you tried running 'top' in a terminal and checking whether the culprit is CPU rather than GPU related? I'm curious why you are certain it is a graphics issue.

Comment: There are minimal processes running, are you looking for anything in particular? I can link a screenshot of psensor showings its the GPU.

Comment: Well, but if it's an integrated GPU, how can you tell? I was just thinking that perhaps some process is pegging your CPU and causing the higher temperature. I'll post an answer for alternate GPU drivers I suppose, in case it helps.

Comment: different "cores" showing different speeds via psensor. I will try this fix tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try updating your Graphics drivers using [Oibaf's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) and seeing if that solves the problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To revert it, install the ppa-purge package,

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

and remove the repository:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the application “macfancltd” (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/macfanctld.1.html)?

I am using a a MacBook 6.2 (mid 2010 - 4Gb ram, GeForce GT 330M dedicated graphics board, and Intel Core I5). Immediately after installation, I realized that the fan speed was not correctly configured, and the MacBook was dangerously overheating, causing the system to freeze.

So, after installing Ubuntu (22.04 - I recommend the new version) on the MacBookPro and ensuring that it has an internet connection, the first issue must be resolved as soon as possible owing to the dangers of overheating:

Open the terminal with control + alt + t and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install macfanctld
```